# actionlib fibonacci_server doesn't move at all

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a beginner to use ROS.
(ubuntu 12.04, and ROS distribution is hydro. but I have installed both groovy and hydro.)

Now, I finished Beginner Level of Core ROS Tutorials and then tried to do actionlib_tutorials.

I only followed the instructions in this URL
(http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29),

> Start a roscore in a new terminal

> $ roscore

Until the section above, I did well.

But in the next section below, I failed.

---

> And then run the action server:

> $ rosrun learning_actionlib

> fibonacci_server You will see something similar to:

> [ INFO] 1250790662.410962000: Started node [/fibonacci], pid [29267], bound on [aqy], xmlrpc port [39746], tcprosport [49573], logging to [~/ros/ros/log/fibonacci_29267.log], using [real] time To check that your action is running properly list topics being published:

---

If I command the sentence below,

> $ rosrun learning_actionlib fibonacci_server

there was no response.

I would like to know why.

If I run the command

> $rostopic list -v
> ,I got these messages.

Published topics:

- /fibonacci/feedback [learning_actionlib/FibonacciActionFeedback] 1 publisher
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
- /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
- /fibonacci/status [actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray] 1 publisher
- /fibonacci/result [learning_actionlib/FibonacciActionResult] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:

- /fibonacci/goal [learning_actionlib/FibonacciActionGoal] 1 subscriber
- /fibonacci/cancel [actionlib_msgs/GoalID] 1 subscriber
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194957/actionlib-fibonacci_server-doesn%27t-move-at-all/) by [W_Kohei](https://answers.ros.org/users/20464/w_kohei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Might be that it is just some logger settings.

To check if the node is running, run the following command `rosnode list` and see if your actionserver pops up. In that casse, you can try to continue with the tutorial and check if the server answers.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [W_Kohei](https://answers.ros.org/users/20464/w_kohei/) on 2014-11-07**:
Thank you for answering my question and I am sorry for my late reply.

If I run the command "rosnode list",
/fibonacci
/rosout
only these words were displayed.
It seems that actionserver doesn't work well....

**Comment by [W_Kohei](https://answers.ros.org/users/20464/w_kohei/) on 2014-11-07**:
Just after fibonacci_server and fibonaccci_client are started, I run that command then I could get these messages"
/fibonacci
/rosout
/test_fibonacci"